# Кривая кириллица при использовании \i в psql

Tags: sql, psql

При использовании кириллицы в файлах с разрешением .sql и попытке занести команды из этого файла в бд через psql \i всё проходит гладко и без ошибок. Правда, в выдаче самой бд записи на русском языке представлены символами, будто бы кодировка сбилась. Если же вносить в таблицу данные напрямую через INSERT INTO  в psql с ру-символами, то всё работает нормально и верно отображается. В чем может быть проблема и как решить?

Пока что у меня даже нет догадок, как это пофиксить. В самом psql регулярно прописываю ! chcp 1251;

Comment: Может пора перейти на utf-8?